# How to add RadioGroup and EditText to AlertDialog?

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

Hi I want to get user name and user gender using alert dialog so I add:

```
AlertDialog.Builder user= new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
     user.setTitle("New Student");
     user.setMessage("What is your Name?");
     final RadioGroup genderRG= new RadioGroup(this);
     RadioButton radiomr = new RadioButton(this);
     radiomr.setText("Mr");
//   radiomr.setId(1);
     genderRG.addView(radiomr);
     RadioButton radiomiss = new RadioButton(this);
     radiomiss.setText("Miss");
//   radiomiss.setId(2);
     genderRG.addView(radiomiss);
     user.setView(genderRG);

     final EditText input = new EditText(this);
     user.setView(input);

     user.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
         {
             @Override
             public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton)
             {
             //  get data                          
             }
         });
     user.setNegativeButton("CANCEL", null);
     user.create().show();
```

But when I run it, It just gives me an EditText.
Please! How can I get Gender and Name in same AlertDialog using radio button or spinner.

Answer (score -1):

You should create your own layout and set it via `setView()`.
You are instead inflating just the EditText, this is why you have just that in the dialog.

In any case it is better to use DialogFragment to create your own dialog version.

More here https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment